# Console.KeyAvailable Fails When Starting a Process

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, system.diagnostics

Here's a snippet of code the works just fine. As I am simulating a long running process, any keystrokes are queued up. The `Console.Available` returns `true` and `false` just as the documentation indicates it should. Everything works great here:

```
while (true) {
   Console.WriteLine("Starting long task...");
   // Simulate some long task by sleeping 3 seconds
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
   Console.WriteLine("Long task is finished.");

   if (Console.KeyAvailable) 
      Console.WriteLine("A key is available: " + Console.ReadKey(false).Key);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("*** No Key available ***");
}
```

---

Here's the problem: When I substitute the `Thread.Sleep()` with code to create and run a real `Process`, the `Console.KeyAvailable` ceases to work. `Console.KeyAvailable` behaves erratically, usually returning `false` but sometimes returning `true` if I type enough keys fast enough.

Has anyone an explanation for this?

```
while (true) {
   LongRunningProcess("someFile.bin");

   if (Console.KeyAvailable) 
      Console.WriteLine("A key is available: " + Console.ReadKey(false).Key);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("*** No Key available ***");
}

private static bool LongRunningProcess(String filename) {
   ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("BlahBlahBlah.exe", filename);
   processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
   p.Start();

   StreamReader stdError = p.StandardError;

   int readResult = stdError.Read();

   p.Close();

   if (readResult != -1) // error was written to std error
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The started process shows a window that becomes the active window. Your console application only receives keyboard input while your console window is the active window. Try setting the `CreateNoWindow` property of the `ProcessStartInfo` to true.